# Ejecutar AJAX de forma dinámica con JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema con AJAX que no se como solucionarlo. Tengo un código que lo que hace es mostrarme una serie de usuarios, cada uno con su ID único. Al principio había hecho la prueba para ver si funcionaba con solamente un usuario, por lo que me funcionaba correctamente, pero a la hora de tener más usuarios me da problemas. El código es el siguiente:

```
<table>
                <?php
                foreach ($chats as $actual) {
                    $nick = $actual["nick_usuario_emisor"];
                    $idEm = $actual["id_usuario_emisor"];
                    $idRec = $actual["id_usuario_receptor"];

                    if ($actual["nick_usuario_emisor"] == $_SESSION["nickSesionIniciada"]) {
                        $nick = $actual["nick_usuario_receptor"];
                        $idEm = $actual["id_usuario_receptor"];
                        $idRec = $actual["id_usuario_emisor"];
                    }
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a id="enlaceChat" href="chatPrueba.php"><?php echo $nick ?></a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="../conexiones/modDatos/estadoSolicitud.php?e=r&ide=<?php echo $idEm ?>&idr=<?php echo $idRec ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
</table>
```

Y este el código que llama a la función de AJAX:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#enlaceChat").click(function(evento) {
                console.log(<?php echo $idEm ?>);
                evento.preventDefault();

                $("#destinoChats").load("chatPrueba.php?id=<?php echo $idEm ?>");
            });
        })
</script>
```

Y la función de AJAX:

```
<script>
        setInterval(obtenerMensajes,3000);
        function obtenerMensajes(){
            var parametros = {
                "id": <?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>,
            };
            $.ajax({
                data: parametros,
                url: '../conexiones/cargarConversaciones.php',
                type: 'post',
                success: function(response) {
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
                    $("#resultado").html("");
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                        $("#resultado").append(jsonData[i][5] + " | " + jsonData[i][6]+"<br>");
                    }
                }

            });
        }
</script>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

El problema está en que estoy llamando a la función del segundo script mediante el ID `#enlaceChat`, que como es único siempre me está pillando él último. Y no se me ocurre como poner para que cada enlace tenga una referencia unica con la que llamar al script, para luego poder coger los correspondientes datos del usuario de la base de datos con AJAX.

La función de AJAX funciona correctamente por que sí que me trae datos, el problema está en la referencia que coge JQUERY de los enlaces.

He pensado en hacer formularios en vez de enlaces para pasarle los datos mediante POST, pero no se si podría darme el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Continué probando hasta que algo me funcionó y fue lo siguiente:

Lo primero cambie el enlace por un botón que luego modificaré con la hoja de estilos, de tal forma que el código queda así:

```
<table>
                <?php
                foreach ($chats as $actual) {
                    $nick = $actual["nick_usuario_emisor"];
                    $idEm = $actual["id_usuario_emisor"];
                    $idRec = $actual["id_usuario_receptor"];

                    if ($actual["nick_usuario_emisor"] == $_SESSION["nickSesionIniciada"]) {
                        $nick = $actual["nick_usuario_receptor"];
                        $idEm = $actual["id_usuario_receptor"];
                        $idRec = $actual["id_usuario_emisor"];
                    }
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button name="btnChat" value="<?php echo $idEm ?>"><?php echo $nick ?></button>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="../conexiones/modDatos/estadoSolicitud.php?e=r&ide=<?php echo $idEm ?>&idr=<?php echo $idRec ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
</table>
```

Y el código de JQUERY queda tal que así:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(evento) {
            $("button[name='btnChat']").click(function(evento) {
                evento.preventDefault();
                $("#destinoChats").load("chat.php?id="+$(this).val());
            });
        })
</script>
```

Con el ID me daba problemas todo el rato, por lo que he probado a ver si se podía hacer por referencia de nombre y sí que dejaba.
El que cambiara el `<a>` por un `<button>` es más que nada por que en el enlace estás "obligado" a poner un href si quieres que se marque como enlace, cosa que en este caso no me interesaba.